# TikZ - flexible arrow positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, arrows, coordinates

The following MWE is translating to the desired `tikz` picture, but the code is not very useful for adjustments. Especially the positioning of some arrows is done very poorly by defining coordinates using millimeter information. The same applies for the dashed frame. Does anybody know a smarter solution to define these coordinates?

```
% document class
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     

% layout (geometry, single page, margins)
\usepackage[a4paper,left=100pt,right=100pt,top=70pt,bottom=70pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

% colorized fonts and frames
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

% flow chart diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel,positioning,graphs}
\usepackage[european,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\tikzstyle{block}       = [draw, fill=anti-flashwhite, rectangle, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=10mm]
\tikzstyle{sum}         = [draw, fill=anti-flashwhite, circle,inner sep=1mm, node distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle{input}       = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output}      = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{branch}      = [circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm,fill=black,draw=black]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle}    = [pin edge={<-,thin,black},pin distance=10mm]
\tikzstyle{skip loop}   = [to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}]
\tikzstyle{hv path}     = [style={to  path={-|  (\tikztotarget)}}]
\tikzstyle{vh path}     = [style={to  path={|-  (\tikztotarget)}}]


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=20mm,>=latex']
    % inputs
    \node [input]   (inputx)                                                        {};
    \node [input]   (inputy)        [below of =inputx, node distance=40mm]          {};

    % sums
    \node [sum]     (sumx1)         [right of=inputx, node distance=15mm]           {};
    \node [sum]     (sumy1)         [right of=inputy, node distance=15mm]           {};

    % controllers
    \node [block]   (reglerx)       [right of=sumx1]                                {Regler $X$};
    \node [block]   (reglery)       [right of=sumy1]                                {Regler $Y$};

    % magnets
    \node [block]   (magnet1)       [right of=reglerx, node distance=40mm]          {Magnet 1};
    \node [block]   (magnet2)       [below of=magnet1]                              {Magnet 2};
    \node [block]   (magnet3)       [right of=reglery, node distance=40mm]          {Magnet 3};

    % sums
    \node [sum]     (sumx2)         [right of=magnet1]                              {};
    \node [sum]     (sumy2)         [right of=magnet3]                              {};

    % pendulums      
    \node [block]   (pendulumx)     [right of=sumx2]                                {Pendel $X$};
    \node [block]   (pendulumy)     [right of=sumy2]                                {Pendel $Y$};

    % branches      
    \node [branch]  (valuex)        [right of=pendulumx, node distance=15mm]        {};
    \node [branch]  (valuey)        [right of=pendulumy, node distance=15mm]        {}; 

    \node [branch]  (dotx)          [above of=valuex]                               {};
    \node [branch]  (doty)          [below of=valuey]                               {};

    \node [branch]  (nonlinearx)    at (55mm,30mm)                                  {};
    \node [branch]  (nonlineary)    at (58mm,-70mm)                                 {};

    % outputs
    \node [output]  (outputx)       [right of=valuex, node distance=10mm]           {};
    \node [output]  (outputy)       [right of=valuey, node distance=10mm]           {};


    % differentiator
    \node [block]   (diffx)         [above of=magnet1]      {$\frac{d x}{d t}$};
    \node [block]   (diffy)         [below of=magnet3]      {$\frac{d y}{d t}$};

    % arrows    
    \draw [->]      (inputx) --     node {$x_{soll}$}   (sumx1);
    \draw [->]      (inputy) --     node {$y_{soll}$}   (sumy1);

    \draw [->]      (sumx1)         --                  (reglerx);
    \draw [->]      (sumy1)         --                  (reglery);

    \draw [->]      (reglerx)       --                  (magnet1);
    \draw [->]      (reglerx.east)  --                  (magnet2.west);
    \draw [->]      (reglerx.east)  --                  (magnet3.west);
    \draw [->]      (reglery.east)  --                  (magnet1.west);     
    \draw [->]      (reglery.east)  --                  (magnet2.west);
    \draw [->]      (reglery)       --                  (magnet3);

    \draw [->]      (magnet1.east)  --                  (sumx2);
    \draw [->]      (magnet1.east)  --                  (sumy2);
    \draw [->]      (magnet2.east)  --                  (sumx2);
    \draw [->]      (magnet2.east)  --                  (sumy2);
    \draw [->]      (magnet3.east)  --                  (sumx2);
    \draw [->]      (magnet3.east)  --                  (sumy2);

    \draw [->]      (sumx2)         --                  (pendulumx);
    \draw [->]      (sumy2)         --                  (pendulumy);

    \draw           (pendulumx)     --                  (valuex);
    \draw           (pendulumy)     --                  (valuey);

    \draw [->]      (valuex)        --      node {$x$}  (outputx);
    \draw [->]      (valuey)        --      node {$y$}  (outputy);

    \draw           (valuex)        --                  (dotx);
    \draw           (valuey)        --                  (doty); 

    \draw [->]      (dotx)          --                  (diffx);
    \draw [->]      (doty)          --                  (diffy);

    \graph{(diffx)  ->[hv path]                         (reglerx)};
    \graph{(diffy)  ->[hv path]                         (reglery)};

    \coordinate (x1) at (65.5mm,3mm);
    \coordinate (y1) at (65.5mm,-3mm);
    \coordinate (x2) at (65.6mm,-17mm);
    \coordinate (y2) at (65.7mm,-23mm);
    \coordinate (x3) at (65.6mm,-37mm);
    \coordinate (y3) at (65.7mm,-43mm);


    \graph{(nonlinearx) ->[vh path, color=red]          (x1)};
    \graph{(nonlinearx) ->[vh path, color=red]          (x2)};
    \graph{(nonlinearx) ->[vh path, color=red]          (x3)};

    \graph{(nonlineary) ->[vh path, color=red]          (y1)};
    \graph{(nonlineary) ->[vh path, color=red]          (y2)};
    \graph{(nonlineary) ->[vh path, color=red]          (y3)};    

    % feedback loops
    \path (dotx)    edge  [->,skip  loop=10mm]          (sumx1);
    \path (doty)    edge  [->,skip  loop=-10mm]         (sumy1);

    % labels
    \coordinate [label=$\dot{x}$] (dotxsign) at         (32mm,6mm);
    \coordinate [label=$\dot{y}$] (dotysign) at         (32mm,-52mm);   

    % dashed frame
    \draw (52mm,35mm)       [dashed,thick, color=blue]  --  (132mm,35mm);
    \draw (132mm,35mm)      [dashed,thick, color=blue]  --  (132mm,-75mm);
    \draw (132mm,-75mm)     [dashed,thick, color=blue]  --  (52mm,-75mm);
    \draw (52mm,-75mm)      [dashed,thick, color=blue]  --  (52mm,35mm);

    % controller communication
    \coordinate (x4) at (32mm,-5mm);
    \coordinate (x5) at (38mm,-5mm);
    \coordinate (y4) at (32mm,-35mm);
    \coordinate (y5) at (38mm,-35mm);

    \draw [->, ultra thick,dotted]      (x4)            --          (y4);   
    \draw [->, ultra thick,dotted]      (y5)            --          (x5);   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define your targets with `xshift` and `yshift`. Your blue frame is much easier drawn as a `rectangle`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\definecolor{myColor1}{named}{red}
\definecolor{myColor2}{named}{blue}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\usepackage[european,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\od}[3][]{\frac{\dif^{#1}#2}{\dif#3^{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
,auto
,>=latex'
,block/.style={text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex,draw, fill=anti-flashwhite, rectangle, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=10mm}
,sum/.style={draw, fill=anti-flashwhite, circle,inner sep=1mm, node distance=20mm}
,input/.style={coordinate}
,output/.style={coordinate}
,branch/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm,fill=black,draw=black}
,skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}}
,frame/.style={dashed,thick,myColor2}
]
\draw
    % inputs
    node [input]   (inputx)                                                        {}
    node [input]   (inputy)        [below = 40mm of inputx]          {}
    % sums
    node [sum]     (sumx1)         [right = 15mm of inputx]           {}
    node [sum]     (sumy1)         [right = 15mm of inputy]           {}
    % controllers
    node [block]   (reglerx)       [right = of sumx1]                                {Regler $X$}
    node [block]   (reglery)       [right = of sumy1]                                {Regler $Y$}
    % magnets
    node [block]   (magnet1)       [right = 30mm of reglerx]          {Magnet 1}
    node [block]   (magnet2)       [below = of magnet1]                              {Magnet 2}
    node [block]   (magnet3)       [right = 30mm of reglery]          {Magnet 3}
    % sums
    node [sum]     (sumx2)         [right = of magnet1]                              {}
    node [sum]     (sumy2)         [right = of magnet3]                              {}
    % pendulums      
    node [block]   (pendulumx)     [right = of sumx2]                                {Pendel $X$}
    node [block]   (pendulumy)     [right = of sumy2]                                {Pendel $Y$}
    % branches      
    node [branch]  (valuex)        [right = of pendulumx]        {}
    node [branch]  (valuey)        [right = of pendulumy]        {}
    node [branch]  (dotx)          [above = 19mm of valuex]                               {}
    node [branch]  (doty)          [below = 19mm of valuey]                               {}
    node [branch]  (nonlinearx)    [above = 24.5mm of reglerx, xshift=20mm]                                  {}
    node [branch]  (nonlineary)    [below = 24.5mm of reglery, xshift=25mm]                                 {}
    % outputs
    node [output]  (outputx)       [right = 15mm of valuex]           {}
    node [output]  (outputy)       [right = 15mm of valuey]           {}
    % differentiator
    node [block]   (diffx)         [above = of magnet1]      {$\od{x}{t}$}
    node [block]   (diffy)         [below = of magnet3]      {$\od{y}{t}$};

    % arrows    
\path 
(inputx) edge[->] node {$x_\text{soll}$} (sumx1)
(sumx1) edge[->] (reglerx)
(reglerx) edge[->] (magnet1)
(magnet1)  edge[->] (sumx2)
(sumx2) edge[->] (pendulumx)
(pendulumx) edge[->] (valuex)
(valuex) edge[->] node {$x$} (outputx);

\path 
(inputy) edge[->] node {$y_\text{soll}$} (sumy1)
(sumy1) edge[->] (reglery)
(reglery) edge[->] (magnet3)
(magnet3)  edge[->] (sumy2)
(sumy2) edge[->] (pendulumy)
(pendulumy) edge[->] (valuey)
(valuey) edge[->] node {$y$} (outputy);

    \draw [->]      (reglerx.east)  --                  (magnet2.west);
    \draw [->]      (reglerx.east)  --                  (magnet3.west);
    \draw [->]      (reglery.east)  --                  (magnet1.west);     
    \draw [->]      (reglery.east)  --                  (magnet2.west);

    \draw [->]      (magnet1.east)  --                  (sumy2);
    \draw [->]      (magnet2.east)  --                  (sumx2);
    \draw [->]      (magnet2.east)  --                  (sumy2);
    \draw [->]      (magnet3.east)  --                  (sumx2);

    \draw           (valuex)        --                  (dotx);
    \draw           (valuey)        --                  (doty); 

    \draw [->]      (dotx)          --                  (diffx);
    \draw [->]      (doty)          --                  (diffy);

    \draw[->] (diffx)  -| node[near end] {$\dot{x}$} (reglerx);
    \draw[->] (diffy)  -| node[near end] {$\dot{y}$} (reglery);

    \draw[->, color=myColor1] (nonlinearx) |- ([yshift=2.5mm]magnet1.west);
    \draw[->, color=myColor1] (nonlinearx) |- ([yshift=2.5mm]magnet2.west);
    \draw[->, color=myColor1] (nonlinearx) |- ([yshift=2.5mm]magnet3.west);

    \draw[->, color=myColor1] (nonlineary) |- ([yshift=-2.5mm]magnet1.west);
    \draw[->, color=myColor1] (nonlineary) |- ([yshift=-2.5mm]magnet2.west);
    \draw[->, color=myColor1] (nonlineary) |- ([yshift=-2.5mm]magnet3.west);
    % feedback loops
    \path (dotx) edge[->,skip loop=10mm] (sumx1);
    \path (doty)    edge  [->,skip  loop=-10mm]         (sumy1);
    % dashed frame
    \draw [frame] ([yshift=10,xshift=-10]nonlinearx) rectangle ([yshift=-38.5,xshift=10]doty);
    % controller communication
    \draw[->, ultra thick,dotted] ([xshift=-2.5mm]reglerx.south) -- ([xshift=-2.5mm]reglery.north);
    \draw[->, ultra thick,dotted] ([xshift=2.5mm]reglery.north) -- ([xshift=2.5mm]reglerx.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Your solution is brilliant. Thank you for adjusting the code so thoughtful.